# gravestone vs headstone difference

Tags: difference

I am trying to figure out a difference between a headstone and a gravestone. Here is what I currently have:

headstone = a horizontal grave element containing typically full name, date of birth, date of death, eventually an epitaph

gravestone = either same as headstone or alternatively it can be also vertically positioned, probably if there is no headstone

Please assist in forming the right opinion about the difference.

context: effort to understand naming of elements of a grave in a cemetery

Thank you.

Comment: Where did you find these definitions? I don't agree with either of them. To my mind, the headstone is vertical, at the **head** end of the grave, whereas a gravestone could be in any position and orientation. A headstone can always  be called a gravestone, but the reverse is not always true. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/headstone https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gravestone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past, a 'gravestone' was a stone laid horizontally to cover a grave, often engraved with information about the deceased such as dates of birth and death, family, etc.

[image]

A' headstone' was a vertical stone placed at the end of the grave nearest the head of the deceased, usually also engraved:

[image]

In modern times, these terms have become interchangeable, and the old idea of a (flat) gravestone is often expressed by 'ledger stone'.

[What Is the Difference Between Headstone, Tombstone and Gravestone?](https://www.milanomonuments.com/blog/what-is-the-difference-between-headstone-tombstone-and-gravestone)